# Is there a way to better perform this task with python? (vlookup with if condition in 2 different dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to this language and I'm just trying to improve my knowledge.

I have the following question, considering 2 different dfs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10, 12, 11, 15, 17, 20, 9, 18, 11, 22, 12, 17, 29, 44, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE_MIN':[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40], 'SCORE_MAX': [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45], 'SCORE':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']})
```

I just would like to add a column to `df1` assigning a 'SCORE' on the basis of the values 'SCORE_MIN', 'SCORE_MAX' of `df2`. To be clear, for the first element of df1 '10', considering that it is greater than or equal to 10 and it is less than 15, the score assigned on the basis of `df2` is equal to "C".

I've unsuccesfully tried `np.where`:

```
df1['SCORE'] = np.where(df1['A'] >= df2['SCORE_MIN'] & df1['A'] < df2['SCORE_MAX'], df2['SCORE'], 'NA')
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: put the result dataframe

Comment: What would you like to do if there are two overlapping intervals in df2? Or is that an impossible case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `merge_asof`:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().sort_values("A")
res = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="A", right_on="SCORE_MIN").set_index("index").sort_index()

print(res)
```

The output is:

```
        A  SCORE_MIN  SCORE_MAX SCORE
index                                
0      10         10         15     C
1      12         10         15     C
2      11         10         15     C
3      15         15         20     D
4      17         15         20     D
5      20         20         25     E
6       9          5         10     B
7      18         15         20     D
8      11         10         15     C
9      22         20         25     E
10     12         10         15     C
11     17         15         20     D
12     29         25         30     F
13     44         40         45     I
14      1          0          5     A
```

Comment: Great. Do you mind accepting my answer for future generations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use np.where you can do this :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10, 12, 11, 15, 17, 20, 9, 18, 11, 22, 12, 17, 29, 44, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE_MIN':[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40], 'SCORE_MAX': [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45], 'SCORE':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']})

a=df1.A.values
bmax=df2.SCORE_MAX.values
bmin=df2.SCORE_MIN.values

i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bmin) & (a[:, None] < bmax))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1.values[i], df2.values[j]]),
    columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns)
)
     A SCORE_MIN SCORE_MAX SCORE
0   10        10        15     C
1   12        10        15     C
2   11        10        15     C
3   15        15        20     D
4   17        15        20     D
5   20        20        25     E
6    9         5        10     B
7   18        15        20     D
8   11        10        15     C
9   22        20        25     E
10  12        10        15     C
11  17        15        20     D
12  29        25        30     F
13  44        40        45     I
14   1         0         5     A
```

Comment: thanks Mathieu, the solution works well for me! it's crystal clear!